# Running Multiple Tkinter Files from an EXE

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, exe

I've built a tkinter GUI that allows me to run seperate .py files by clicking a button. Every button (of 11) opens a seperate .py file and runs it. I have no issues running in pycharm, however after converting it to a file, using the first page as the executable, only that file runs. I don't currently have the files set to import in the main code, and when I do that launches it immediately after opening the main exe.

I have tried adding the files afterwords (though the exact command line eludes me right now), and I've also tried a .spec file, which only opens the other pages after I close the first (even if I don't click any buttons). The one thing that has worked has been importing the files after running the definition associated with the corresponding buttons. This however lets it run once and then never again. Any advice?

Comment: Show a minimal code example that reproduces the problem. It's unclear exactly how you run Python files or how you pass a file path to a button command.